# Dreamweaver testing slider in Chrome not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dreamweaver

I'm testing a video slider which plays the next video when the previous video ends.
It works in Dreamweaver but does not in Chrome. Is it because Chrome can't run `onended` or smth?

HTML / JS

```
<head>
    <link href="Sliderteststyle2.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <video autoplay  id="video1" class="video1">
        <source src="Komp 1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video   id="video2" class="video2">
        <source src="Komp 2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video   id="video3" class="video3">
        <source src="Komp 3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <video   id="video4" class="video4">
        <source src="Komp 4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
        <video   id="video5" class="video5">
        <source src="Komp 5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
        <video   id="video6" class="video6">
        <source src="Komp 6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>


</body>
</html>
<script>

var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');
var video2 = document.getElementById('video2');
var video3 = document.getElementById('video3');
var video4 = document.getElementById('video4');
var video5 = document.getElementById('video5');
var video6 = document.getElementById('video6');

function imgTransition(){
    imagen1.style.opacity=0;
    video1.play();
    video1.style.opacity=1;
}
video1.onended = function(){
    video2.play();
    video1.style.opacity=0;
    video2.style.opacity=1;
}
video2.onended = function(){
    video3.play();
    video2.style.opacity=0;
    video3.style.opacity=1;
}
video3.onended = function(){
    video4.play();
    video3.style.opacity=0;
    video4.style.opacity=1;
}
video4.onended = function(){
    video5.play();
    video4.style.opacity=0;
    video5.style.opacity=1;
}
video5.onended = function(){
    video6.play();
    video5.style.opacity=0;
    video6.style.opacity=1;
}
video6.onended = function(){
    video1.play();
    video6.style.opacity=0;
    video1.style.opacity=1;
}

</script>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}

video{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    transition: all 1.2s linear;
    z-index: -10;
}

.video1{
    opacity:1;
}
.video2{
    opacity:0;
}
.video3{
    opacity:0;
}
.video4{
    opacity:0;
}
.video5{
    opacity:0;
}
.video6{
    opacity:0;
}


.imagenes{
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2s;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    object-fit:cover;
    z-index: -10;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: `onended ` is allowed anyway, are you sure the DOM is loaded when `video1.onended` is being defined ? You can add some breakpoints in chrome to check..

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I opened the console in Chrome now and saw a few [erorrs](https://imgur.com/a/dzwj0j1). Any way to fix this?

Comment: Ahh okay, so you need to reference your jsvscrippt files in the HTML `<script src="javascript.js"></script>` a 404 error means it could not find them. Make sure your path for the javascript files is correct. 
`

Comment: Looks like dreamweaver has some kind of preiew util built in.. https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/device-preview-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do was to add `muted` to my video tag